# Error after upgrading MikTeX (interfaces and pgfkeys)

Tags: errors, pgfkeys, interfaces

I have a compilation problem with an old document, which I cannot recompile today with an up to date MiKTex 2.9 installation on Windows.

It seems that it is a problem with latest version of `pgfkeys`.
Here's my minimal example that shows the error:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{interfaces}

\sectionformat\section[hang]{
    label=,
    labelsep=,
    font=\bfseries\normalsize\color{blue!80!black},
    top=16pt plus 1pt minus 1pt,
    bottom=2pt,
}

\begin{document}
truc
    \end{document}
```

With that and using XeLaTex (i have the same error with PdfLaTex)

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<inserted text> \itf 
                     @setlength \itf @sk {####1}\noexpand \pgfkeysEsetvalue ...
l.15 }
```

I have added explicitly `pgf` package on top of the source, but the error is always here.

Comment: don't use this interfaces package. It tries to patch lots of other packages but is unmaintained since 2011 and doesn't keep track of changes.

Comment: ok, i'll try to replace interfaces, but the document is old and works well for years. If i understand, intefrfaces is no longer maintained. I have to work to replace that code with another. do you have some tips to do that ?

Comment: Add \makeatletter before the \sectionformat, then it will again compile. But there is no garanty that it doesn't break in some other place in the future.

Comment: Regarding a replacement for interfaces: simply use the commands of the original packages to setup things.

Answer (score 0):

Ulrike Fischer is right, the problem come from interfaces package.

With `\makeatletter` the code compile and produce the correct output. But for the future, I have replaced the interfaces command with titlesec commands.

```
\titlelabel{}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]{\bfseries\normalsize\color{blue!80!black}}{}{0pt}{}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{16pt plus 1pt minus 1pt}{2pt}
```

Now I have exactly the same output, and I hope it will be more stable for the future.

I used the Interfaces package because I found its syntax easy and readable for this kind of configuration; in any case simpler and more readable than titlesec directly (for this example).

But well, since it is no longer maintained, it must be removed and replaced.